# php command line doesn't send to the script proper prompted input from user

Tags: stdin, php

php command line doesn't send to the script proper prompted input from user. his is an example of the issue

`is_dir("C:/");` return 1 but `is_dir(fgets(STDIN))` return null after user input `"C:/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`is_dir(trim(fgets(STDIN)))`

I think the raw inputs must be `c:/ + ENTER KEY`